# Chrome doesn't show anything nor is clickable

Tags: jquery-chosen

I just tried chosen and in my initial tests (FF) worked fine, but now checking in another browsers is not.

In Firefox, Explorer, Edge is showing fine but in Opera or Chrome doesn't show anything, nor is clickable but inspecting the source, the list elements are present.

I see the sample page in chrome and is working, so, something is wrong on my side but I am not able to even start to look at it. Any advise is welcome.

Versions: (doesn't work)
Chrome: 44.0.2403.157
Opera: 12:16 (1860)

Version working:
Firefox 40.0.3
IE: 11.0.9600.17937

Jquery: 1.6.4 (downloaded yesterday and served locally, not in the CDN)
Chosen 1.4.2  (downloaded yesterday)

You can see in the image the behavior. IN FF, IE  the drop down shows the countries as expected.

You can try this now in  http://eventos.ai.org.mx/encuentro/registration.php and you can get the files if you need.

Also is the same screen in FF.

Thanks for your time and any help,

[image: CHosen.js in FF]

[image: Chosen.JS in Opera or Chrome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stylesheet chosen.css on row 160 there is a defined class `.chosen-container .chosen-results`. Add a floating property to the class:

```
.chosen-container .chosen-results {
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
  max-height: 287px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  float: left;
  width: 99%;
}
```

`float: left;` will push it to the place.

`width: 99%;` will set the correct width for every row.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much.